# Questions of the proof of proposition 9.2 from commutative algebra by Atiyah

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, field-theory

[Proposition 9.2 in Atiyah's commutative algebra book](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4109600/proposition-9-2-in-atiyahs-commutative-algebra-book)

I have read this related proof of proposition 9.2 (ii)=>(iii).

Here's the part of this proposition I need.

**Proposition 9.2.**
Let $A$ be a Noetherian local domain of dimension one, $\mathfrak{m}$ its
maximal ideal, $k = A/\mathfrak{m}$ its residue field. Then the following are equivalent:

ii) $A$ is integrally closed;

iii) $\mathfrak{m}$ is a principal ideal;

Here is the proof of this implication.

Let $a\in\mathfrak{m}$ and $a\neq 0$. By remark (A) there exists an integer $n$ such that $m^n\subset (a)$, $\mathfrak{m}^{n-1}\nsubseteq (a)$. Choose $b\in\mathfrak{m}^{n-1}$ and $b\notin(a)$, and let $x=a/b\in K,$ the fraction field of $A$. We have $x^{-1}\notin A$(since $b\notin (a)$), hence $x^{-1}$ is not integral over $A$, and therefore by (5.1) we have $x^{-1}\mathfrak{m}\nsubseteq\mathfrak{m}$(for if $x^{-1}\mathfrak{m}\subset\mathfrak{m}$, $\mathfrak{m}$ would be a faithful $A[x^{-1}]$-module, finitely generated as an $A-module$). But $x^{-1}\mathfrak{m}\subset A$ by construction of $x$, hence $x^{-1}\mathfrak{m}=A$ and therefore $\mathfrak{m}=Ax=(x)$.

Now it is clear why $x^{-1}\mathfrak{m}$ is an ideal and how one can define the set $x^{-1}\mathfrak{m}$.

The next question remains:

If $x^{-1}\mathfrak{m}\subset\mathfrak{m}$, then Why $\mathfrak{m}$ would be a faithful $A[x^{-1}]$-module, and finitely generated as an $A$-module? (I knew that the ideals in Noetherian ring are finitely generated.)

Comment: What exactly is unclear to you in point 2?

Comment: $\mathfrak{m}$ would be a faithful $A[x^{-1}]$-module, and finitely generated as an $A$-module  This is the part which is unclear to me.

Comment: The module $\mathfrak{m}$ is a faithful $A[x^{-1}]$-module and 
finitely generated as an $A$-module since the ring $A$ is 
a Noetherian domain by condition.

Comment: Could I know what is the addition and the multiplication of module m？ Moreover A[$ x^{-1} $] is the set that collect all the polynomials which substitute x to $ x^{-1} $, right? And it's also a ring, right?

Comment: I still dont know why it's a faithful A[$ x^{-1} $]-module. Could you show me why the Ann(m)=0 is correct? Could I also have the addition and the multiplication of module m？   Just to confirm, A[$ x^{-1} $] is the set that collect all the polynomials which substitute x to $ x^{-1} $, right? And it's also a ring, right?

Comment: see  Supplement 2 to my answer.

Comment: Sorry, I still have some problems.
1. Why it's a faithful A[$x^{-1}$]-module, not A-module? Could I know the addition operation and multiplication operation of the A[$x^{-1}$]-module?
2. Moreover, why if it's a A[$x^{-1}$]-module, then it's a finitely generated A-module?
3. And what's the contradiction to let us know that $x^{-1}m \nsubseteq m$ should be true?

Comment: Also, the elements in A[$x^{-1}$] just the polynomials substitute x by $x^{-1}$, right? Additionally,  is there any goood materials to let me read to help me to understand this proof?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answer to the first question.  I use the notations and facts stated on this page of the book.

Since $b\in\mathfrak{m}^{n-1}$ and $x=a/b$ it follows that for any $v\in\mathfrak{m}$ we have $bv\in\mathfrak{m}^n\subset(a)$ and so $bv=ay$ for some $y\in A$ hence
$$
x^{-1}v=\frac{bv}{a}=\frac{ay}{a}=y.
$$

**Supplement.**

So we understand that $x^{-1}\mathfrak{m}\subset A$. Then since $\mathfrak{m}$ is an ideal, for any $z\in A$ we have $zx^{-1}\mathfrak{m}=x^{-1}(z\mathfrak{m})\subset x^{-1}\mathfrak{m}$ and
$x^{-1}\mathfrak{m}+x^{-1}\mathfrak{m}=x^{-1}\mathfrak{m}$. It follows that $x^{-1}\mathfrak{m}$ is an ideal in $A$. Last, since $A$ is a local ring and $x^{-1}\mathfrak{m}\not\subset\mathfrak{m}$ it follows that $x^{-1}\mathfrak{m}=A$.

**Supplement 2.**

Since $K$ is the fraction field of ring $A$ and $\mathfrak{m}\subset  A\subset K$, $x^{-1}\in K$, it follows that if $vt=0$ for $v\in\mathfrak{m}$ and $t\in A[x^{-1}]$, then either $v=0$ or $t=0$ and so $\mathfrak{m}$ is a faithful $A[x^{-1}]$-module.

**Supplement 3.**

I can't understand what's confusing you.

Here are the answers to your questions from your comment.
Here is the logic of reasoning:

1. by choice $x^{-1}\notin A$ and therefore is not integral over $A$ (by convention ring $A$ is integrally closed);
2. we know that $\mathfrak{m}$ is an ideal in $A$ and
   if $x^{-1}\mathfrak{m}\subset\mathfrak{m}$,
   then $\mathfrak{m}$ is an $A[x^{-1}]$-module.
   Since $\mathfrak{m}$ is finitely generated as an $A$-module ($A$ is a Noetherian ring) and
   $\mathfrak{m}$ is a faithful $A[x^{-1}]$-module ($A$ is an integral domain), it follows from Proposition 5.1 that $x^{-1}$
   is integral over $A$. Contradiction.
   Hence we conclude that $x^{-1}\mathfrak{m}\not\subset\mathfrak{m}$.

Why if $x^{-1}\mathfrak{m}\subset\mathfrak{m}$, then $\mathfrak{m}$ is an $A[x^{-1}]$-module?

By the definition of module, it is sufficient to check only $tv\in\mathfrak{m}$ for any $v\in\mathfrak{m}$ and $t\in A[x^{-1}]$. It follows from the fact that $x^{-1}\mathfrak{m}\subset\mathfrak{m}$ and ring $A[x^{-1}]$ is generated by ring $A$ and $x^{-1}$, i.e. the elements in $A[x^{−1}]$ are polynomials of $x^{−1}$ with coefficients from $A$.

3. $x^{-1}\mathfrak{m}\subset A$ by construction of $x$;
4. since $A$ is local ring and $\mathfrak{m}$ its only maximal ideal and $x^{-1}\mathfrak{m}$  is also an ideal not lying in $\mathfrak{m}$,
   it follows that
   $x^{-1}\mathfrak{m}=A$ and $\mathfrak{m}=xA=(x)$.

**Supplement 4.**

Answers to the questions in the comment below

1. Correct.
2. I don't understand this question. On the contrary $\mathfrak{m}^n\subset(a)$. Perhaps you are asking why $\mathfrak{m}^{n-1}\not\subset(a)$?
   If $\mathfrak{m}\subset(a)$, then $\mathfrak{m}=(a)$ ($\mathfrak{m}$ is a maximal ideal in $A$). So $\mathfrak{m}$ is a principal ideal with generating $a$. This is what we are proving.
   If $\mathfrak{m}\not\subset(a)$, then there exists such $n$ that 2 conditions $\mathfrak{m}^n\subset(a)$ and $\mathfrak{m}^{n-1}\not\subset(a)$ simultaneously hold.
3. Absolutely not. See (iv) of Proposition 5.1. The role of $M$ is played by the ideal $\mathfrak{m}$.

The part of Proposition 5.1 that we need can be formulated like this:

> **Proposition 5.1.** The following are equivalent:
>
> i) $x$ is integral over A;
>
> iv) There exists a faithful $A[x]$-module $M$ which is finitely
> generated as an $A$-module.

4. Recall $x=a/b$ and $b\notin(a)$. If $x^{-1}=b/a\in A$, then $b\in aA=(a)$.

Comment: But why $ x^{-1}m$ is an ideal, if it's just a collection of some elements in A？

Comment: Does it just use the fact that $ x^{-1}$v=(bv)/a to check it is an ideal of A? Or we can show it's an ideal by some other propositions or Theorems?

Comment: I got it. Thank you very much.

Comment: Sorry, I still have some problems.
1. Why it's a faithful A[$x^{-1}$]-module, not A-module? Could I know the addition operation and multiplication operation of the A[$x^{-1}$]-module?
2. Moreover, why if it's a A[$x^{-1}$]-module, then it's a finitely generated A-module?
3. And what's the contradiction to let us know that $x^{-1}m \nsubseteq m$ should be true?

Comment: Also, the elements in A[$x^{-1}$] just the polynomials substitute x by $x^{-1}$, right? Additionally,  is there any goood materials to let me read to help me to understand this proof?

Comment: Yes, the elements in $A[x^{-1}]$ are polynomials of $x^{-1}$ with coefficients from $A$. There are such books on commutative algebra: Zarisski, Samuel; Nicolas Bourbaki. But these books are even more difficult for the beginner. The answers to the rest of your questions are in the appendix to my post.

Comment: Sorry, I still have some questions.
1. For supplement2, why if vt=0 implies either v=0 or t=0? I know that A is an ID, but t isn't in A.
2. For supplement3-2, why m is an A[$x^{-1}$]-module? And why m is not only just an finitely generated A-module, but also an finitely generated A[$x^{-1}$]-module?

Comment: Moreover, could I know the addition and the multiplication of A[$x^{-1}$]-module m?

Comment: 1) Note that $A,t\subset K$ and $K$ is the fraction field of the ring $A$.

2) The fact that if $x^{-1}\mathfrak{m}\subset\mathfrak{m}$, then $\mathfrak{m}$ $A[x^{-1}]$-module added to item 2 of Supplement 3.

3) Since $A<A[x^{-1}]$, any finitely generated $A$-module is a finitely generated $A[x^{-1}]$-module.

Comment: Sorry, I still have one question. I know that A is an integral domain, but I think we can't assure that A[$x^{-1}$] is also an integral domain. SO for supplement2, why vt=0 can implies that either v=0 or t=0? Additionally, when v is not 0, how can we assure that t=0 is still true?

Comment: I'll try again.
If $A$ is an integral domain,  
then there exists a field containing $A$, 
the minimal field $K$ containing $A$ is called the field of fractions of $A$
(see the remark on page 37 of Atiyah-Macdonald's).
In our case, $0\neq x\in K$ means $x^{-1}\in K$, so $A[x^{-1}]\subset K$. 
Every zero divisor in the ring $A[x^{-1}]$ is a zero divisor in the field $K$. 
But a field has no nonzero zero divisors!

Comment: 1. So you mean since v and t both are not zero divisor, therefore Ann(m)=0, right? (The faithful part.)
2. Additionally for remark(A), why $m^{n} \nsubseteq (a)$ is true?
3. This question is refer to Supplement3-2. I know that m is a finitely generated A[$x^{-1}$]-module, but by proposition5.1 it says that if "A[x] is a finitely generated A-module then $x\in B$, is integral over A. Is m=A[$x^{-1}$]? If not, then why $x^{-1}$ is integral over A?
4. Why $x^{-1}\notin A$?

Comment: @JudyJudy See supplement 4.

Comment: I got it. Thank you very much.

Comment: @JudyJudy Glad to be of help.